# 'Missing keyword' this error is coming while i create a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, error-handling, create-table

'Missing keyword' this error is coming while I create a table using the below query:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCTS
(
ACCT_NO NUMBER (12),
ACCTH_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
ACCTH_ADD VARCHAR2(100),
ACCTH_STATE VARCHAR2(50),
ACCTH_DOB DATE ,
ACCT_DT_CREATED DATE,
BRANCH_CODE NUMBER(5),
ACCT_TYPE_CODE NUMBER(6),
CONSTRAINT ACCT_NO_PK PRIMARY KEY (ACCT_NO),
CONSTRAINT ACCTH_STATE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (ACCTH_STATE) REFERENCES STATES (STATE_ID),
CONSTRAINT ACCT_TYPE_CODE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (ACCT_TYPE_CODE) REFERENCES ACCT_TYPES(ACCT_TYPE_CODE)
)
```

Comment: The error message should show exactly **where** Oracle thinks it found that error (line of code and exact position, or character, where the error was found). It is always important to show the **complete** error message, not just its summary.

Answer (score 1):

I added your query to SQL Fiddle (adding the missing tables so the foreign key constraints will work) and the query works:

```
CREATE TABLE STATES
(
  STATE_ID VARCHAR2(50),
  CONSTRAINT ACCT_STATE_ID PRIMARY KEY (STATE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ACCT_TYPES
(
  ACCT_TYPE_CODE NUMBER(6),
  CONSTRAINT ACCT_TYPES_ID PRIMARY KEY (ACCT_TYPE_CODE)
);

CREATE TABLE ACCTS
(
  ACCT_NO NUMBER (12),
  ACCTH_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
  ACCTH_ADD VARCHAR2(100),
  ACCTH_STATE VARCHAR2(50),
  ACCTH_DOB DATE ,
  ACCT_DT_CREATED DATE,
  BRANCH_CODE NUMBER(5),
  ACCT_TYPE_CODE NUMBER(6),
  CONSTRAINT ACCT_NO_PK PRIMARY KEY (ACCT_NO),
  CONSTRAINT ACCTH_STATE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (ACCTH_STATE) REFERENCES STATES (STATE_ID),
  CONSTRAINT ACCT_TYPE_CODE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (ACCT_TYPE_CODE) REFERENCES ACCT_TYPES(ACCT_TYPE_CODE)
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b726da

Comment: Yeah i had created that table before this one but still error is coming. Also is it mandatory that PK of one table should be PK of other table.?

Comment: IF you have two tables with the same PK (not just the same column name, but the same data, and cross-related) then you probably should revisit your data model. See "Third Normal Form".

Comment: A foreign key must reference a primary key in another table (or at least a column with a unique constraint; maybe it does not have to be a primary key).  The SQL code I have given I have typed exactly as is into Oracle and it worked. I do not see why your SQL causes an error, if your foreign key constraints work.

Comment: @DavidSugar - with the clarification that the "other" table may sometimes, in fact, be "the same" table. (Perhaps not the case here, but some people are confused by this, so it is best to state it correctly every time.)